# Gitlab CI/CD - How to package a dependency library downloaded from packages & registries using Dependency:get

Tags: maven, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I am able to download the dependency successfully

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=my.package.lib:SharedLib:0.0.1 -DremoteRepositories=gitlab-maven::::https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/23422/packages/maven
```

The problem is this command doesn't package the jar. When I add package or install to the command:

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=my.package.lib:SharedLib:0.0.1 -DremoteRepositories=gitlab-maven::::https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/23422/packages/maven package
```

I get an error saying it can't find the SharedLib dependency in nexus. How do i get the dependency SharedLib to be found when my maven project is packaged in CI/CD?